# How can I get prices list from EAN or UPC code?

Tags: ios

I 'm developing Barcode scanner app.

Now,I'm wondering how to get price lists from ean or upc code which I input by using Amazon search or Google product search.

I can see this function in RedLaser iphone app,but I can't guess how to do this.

I've already implemented Barcode scanner,but from scanned result(i.e ean code or upc code) I want to get prices list or company name ,etc.

Please help me.